# Extracting particular characters/ text from DataFrame column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the email provider from the mail column of the Dataframe and create a new column named "Mail_Provider". For example, taking gmail from a@gmail.com and storing it in "Mail_Provider" column. Also I would like to extract Country ISD fro Phone column and Create a new column for that. Is there any other straight/simpler method other than regex.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["A","B","C"],"mail": 
["a@gmail.com","b@yahoo.com","c@gmail.com"],"Adress": 
["Adress1","Adress2","Adress3"],"Phone":["+91-1234567890","+88- 
0987654321","+27-2647589201"]})
```

Table

```
Name   mail        Adress       Phone

A    a@gmail.com   Adress1  +91-1234567890
B    b@yahoo.com   Adress2  +88-0987654321
C    c@gmail.com   Adress3  +27-2647589201
```

Result expected:-

```
Name   mail        Adress       Phone        Mail_Provider   ISD

A    a@gmail.com   Adress1  +91-1234567890    gmail           91
B    b@yahoo.com   Adress2  +88-0987654321    yahoo           88
C    c@gmail.com   Adress3  +27-2647589201    gmail           27
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda function will work

```py
data['Mail_Provider'] = data['mail'].apply(lambda x: x.split("@")[1].split(".")[0])

data['ISD'] = data['Phone'].apply(lambda x: x.split("+")[1].split("-")[0])
```

Answer (score 9):

Regex is rather simple as these:

```
data['Mail_Provider'] = data['mail'].str.extract('\@(\w+)\.')

data['ISD'] = data['Phone'].str.extract('\+(\d+)-')
```

If you really want to avoid regex, @Eva's answer would be the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Mixed approach (regex and simple slicing):

```
In [693]: df['Mail_Provider'] = df['mail'].str.extract('@([^.]+)')

In [694]: df['ISD'] = df['Phone'].str[1:3]

In [695]: df
Out[695]: 
  Name         mail   Adress           Phone Mail_Provider ISD
0    A  a@gmail.com  Adress1  +91-1234567890         gmail  91
1    B  b@yahoo.com  Adress2  +88-0987654321         yahoo  88
2    C  c@gmail.com  Adress3  +27-2647589201         gmail  27
```

Comment: My guess is `ISD` can be anywhere from 1 to 3 digits, that's why I used regex for it as well.

Comment: @QuangHoang, in this case I relied on the OP's request  *"other straight/simpler method other than regex"*. I have no troubles with regex approaches (if required)

Comment: Ha, I totally overlooked that piece of information.